# iOS - Creating a blurred layer using CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I created a CALayer with white color and 0.4 of opacity. What I want to is to make this layer above an image and make it blur, like the notification layer is blurring on the app or the home screen you're opening here's my CALayer:

```
CALayer *lyr = [CALayer layer];
lyr.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 190, 190);
lyr.position = CGPointMake(90, 50);
lyr.backgroundcolor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
lyr.opacity = 0.4f;
[self.view.layer addSubLayer:lyr];
```

Sorry if I didn't explained what I need exactly

 Thanks in Advance

Comment: maybe go this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view

Comment: Didn't these code work?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `FXBlurView`
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

It also provides a method to apply a tinted blur on an image.

`- (UIImage *)blurredImageWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius iterations:(NSUInteger)iterations tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;`

-> Import `UIImage+FXBlurImage.h`