# UIVisualEffectView renders differently on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

In my `ViewController.swift`:

```
var img = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "puddles"))

img.frame = view.bounds;
view.addSubview(img);


var effect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
var effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
effectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)
view.addSubview(effectView)
```

The image as rendered using the code above in the `iPad Air`, `iPhone 5`, or `iPhone 5S` simulators:

[image: woof, doesn't that look so good]

The image as rendered using the code above in the `iPhone 4S`, `iPad 2`, or `iPad Retina` simulators:

[image: I can't see my doge!]

*Note: Both images above were taken from the simulator, but this can be reproduced on actual devices running iOS 8 Beta 1 as well.*

Obviously, I would like to achieve the first effect on all devices. How can I achieve the same first effect on all devices?

Comment: You're using Swift in your code sample, but there's nothing about your question that depends on that. Please use [swift-language] only for questions about the language.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`UIVisualEffectView` in iOS 8 does pretty much the same thing as the (formerly private API) translucency and vibrancy effects seen in iOS 7. Like the iOS 7 effects, they fall back to graphically simpler implementations on hardware that can't render such complex graphics effects in realtime.

Comment: This is interesting, but not surprising. By looking at something like Control Center you can see the exact same effect being rendered. On devices like the iPad Retina, in Control Center there is no blurring at all, just like in my question. I didn't even notice this. It seems like `UIVisualEffectView` is meant for toolbars and similar, and that if I simply want to blur the background I should probably use static blurring or something like [`FXBlurView`](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView).

Comment: I just spent 2 hours trying to understand why the stupid view wasn't displaying blur, despite having used it fine in another project.  Turns out I was using the iPad 2 simulator... which you found to show white.  Ugh, painful.  Wish they had a static mode versus live mode instead of this fall back... pretty different look.

Comment: Wow, I want 1,5 hours of my life back Apple. They 'might' want to add (read: SHOULD DEFINITELY) this to the docs...

Answer (score 5):

We hit this issue recently when our Visual Effect View was an ugly grey color on one of our developer's machines.

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
```

It turns out that they had enabled `Low Quality Graphics Override` on their iOS Simulator. Turning this option back to `Device Default` fixes the issue and displays a nice translucent view.

> iOS Simulator > Menu Bar > Debug > Graphics Quality Override > Device Default

[image: Low quality graphics override option in iOS Simulator]

Comment: You are awesome, it saves me from keep porting it to device just to test the blur effect. thanks man!