# How to use UIVibrancyEffect (iOS 8) for a Label within a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios8, xcode6, uivibrancyeffect

I have watched WWDC2014 and wanted to try the UIVibrancyEffect right away, I have succeed in using UIBlurEffect. However, the Vibrancy Effect confused me a lot as it requires to use with UIBlurEffectView.

Here is the hierarchy:

- Root View (UIView) (I have set backgroundColor to a image)
- (Inserted a Blur View By **Code**)
- UITableView
- UITableViewCell (Custom)
- UILabel *<--- want to apply here ^.^*

I have the above in my **storyboard**.

I have changed the Root View Background with a image, and added UIBlurEffectView, I want to apply UIVibrancyEffect to my Label in the UITableViewCell.

Please kindly give advice.

Comment: Can you insert the UIVisualEffectView at the beginning of UITableViewCell's view hierarchy?

Comment: I have looked at [how-to-use-uivisualeffectview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview), the label should be in vibrancyEffectView and vibrancyEffectView should be in blurview. I have some reasons that I want my background extend to the navigation bar so I could not set the blur effect at the beginning of UITableViewCell's view hierarchy.

Comment: And you can't put the blur view in the cell...

Comment: `Do not add subviews directly to the UIVisualEffectView itself.`