# iOS blur effect to ImageView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, blur

I am trying to make simple iOS app. I need to make image view with blur effect.
I found this code on Stack Overflow:

```
class BlurImageView: UIImageView {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)   
      var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
      var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
      effectView.frame = frame
      addSubview(effectView)
  }
}
```

And I need to connect this class to my `image_view`, but I don't know how to do it.
I try to do it in my `view_did_load` function in my `ViewController` (`image_view` is a outlet)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    image_view = BlurImageView()
}
```

but `NSCoder` required... What is it? maybe my way is a wrong way?

Comment: Added blur effect with
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `image_view` an instance of `BlurImageView`, so in your view controller and where your `image_view` is an outlet, you need to make it an instance of `BlurImageView` and not an instance of an `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need it. The reason why you're not seeing results is because you're attempting to initialize the class from a different initializer than the one you setup.

Try:

```
class BlurImageView: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init() {
        var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
        effectView.frame = frame
        addSubview(effectView)
    }
}
```