# How to make app background transparent like notification in swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, background, blur, uiblureffect

Is there any reference to make an application to have a transparent background and looks like notification, so wallpaper still remain in the background when my apps running when my wallpaper has a blur effect ?

Comment: I hope you can use this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317292/ios-blur-effect-to-image-view-with-swift

Comment: In iOS 13, this is finally possible! See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think it's possible.
[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image) to an answer that suggests a private method that allowed the functionality in iOS7.

The comments note that the private method stopped working from iOS 8.2

I imagine Apple didn't like the idea of Apps being able to either

- Fake the home screen whilst still inside an app (users might get confused and enter bank details into a fake banking app)
- Allow apps to capture a user's background

It's a shame because it could add to some nice effects like those used in iBooks and the iOS dialler.