# BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, xcode6

**UPDATE: Reference #19285042 and submit bug reports to apple**

Very weird error and not finding anything online. Its saying "BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted"

I'm just doing some basic filter applications. The error message ONLY occurs if I reassign the UIImageView.image to another UIImage. If I comment out just that line I will not get the error. So if you can think of any reason why this message appears when I assign a filtered image to a UIImageView that would be incredibly helpful.

If you can suggest any cause for this error I would appreciate it.

```
#import "FilterTestsViewController.h"

@interface FilterTestsViewController ()

@end

@implementation FilterTestsViewController

UIImage* _originalImage;
UIImage* _filterImage;
UIImageView* _uiImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initialize];
    //flip image by 180*

}

-(void)initialize
{
    _originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ja.jpg"]; //creates image from file, this will result in a nil CIImage but a valid CGImage;
    [self createFilterImage];
    _uiImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_filterImage]; //creates a UIImageView with the UIImage
    [self.view addSubview:_uiImageView]; //adds the UIImageView to view;
}

-(void)createFilterImage
{
    NSString* filterName = @"CIFalseColor";
    CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:_originalImage.CGImage];
    CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey,ciImage, nil];
    _filterImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[filter outputImage]];
}

@end
```

Comment: I got the same error in XCode 6 also using CIFilters in a very similar manner. I've never seen BSXPC before though, and I don't know what it is. I found this gist displaying the same problem in a very different context: https://gist.github.com/saurabh360/19d739e3c0ccee1caf34

Comment: I have no clue, but if I turn something up I'll answer this.

Comment: This has something to do with memory in ios 8. When I run the same code through Xcode 5 and ios 7, I get a memory warning, but for whatever reason it's not being generated in ios 8. The memory profiler through Xcode 6 also doesn't show increased memory usage. So, I'm not quite sure what the story is.

Comment: For me this issue is happening when using CIContext in iOS8. Commented out that code and returned the image without CI manipulation (such as Gaussian blur) and it ran fine.

Comment: This is pretty bad! Couldn't find the issue at Apple bug reporter, issued mine as #20384576 FWIW.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The message you are getting is due to a CIFilter bug in iOS 8.

XPC Services are meant to [reduce crashes by isolating less stable components](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) such as filters and plugins. This is usually not fatal and the connection will be restored by launchd restarting the service. Since this is not a long running service, but simply an operation, chances are that your image filter is not actually being applied.

This is very much a bug in iOS 8, and you *should* file a [Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) (bug report) to let Apple know that (yet another piece of) iOS 8 has a bug.

If you are going to do that, you should install [Quick Radar](http://www.quickradar.com/), keep track of the Radar number, and reply to the many other similar questions on Stack Overflow with the same issue. Encourage other people to file a duplicate Radar report referencing your original issue. That will give the bug more attention at Apple.

Apple really rushed this one out. The [previously mentioned workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview/24083728#24083728) is fine if you can make a different CIFilter subclass do what you want. Otherwise, you will just have to tinker around with copying the image, saving its NSData representation, or otherwise removing it from the CIImage workflow in some other way.

Comment: I did and they stopped replying. But I do appreciate the extra info!

Comment: Would you mind giving us the Radar bug number? I'll edit this question so that it contains the solution, which will be, "File a duplicate Radar referencing this original Radar." Then you can choose this as the "Solution". This will get other people to file a duplicate Radar, getting Apple's attention.

Comment: I added my number for the bug report

Comment: Any news if this bug has been fixed? I'm experiencing similar issues to the poster.

Comment: I also have a similar problem using CIFilters with OpenGLES. Any solutions posted?

Answer (score 5):

From reading a [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift) article, I found that adding an option to the context, so that rendering is done in the CPU rather than the GPU, will remove the warning.

`let context = CIContext(options:[kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : true])`

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was occurring when I would try to use CIFilters in iOS8+ for some reason?

I added some code to check iOS version and if it was greater than 7.9.9 I would use a CIFilter substitute that's iOS8+ like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083728/2057171

On a separate side-note, xCode6 had removed CIFilter framework from my project altogether (strange), but adding it back didn't fix this crash...

Comment: I just had this come up when the Game Center GKMatchmaker dialog appeared.  That's Apple's own dialog, and I guess they're doing something that CI didn't like.

Comment: Looking back on this I was able to make actual CIFilters work, i just had to code them a different way, I dont remember what I did, it was a while back, but I think it had to do with not running the CIFilter on the main thread or something (which you could do in iOS7 but they stopped you from doing in iOS8 for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**OBJ-C**

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer:@(YES)}];
```

**Swift**

```
let context = CIContext(options:[kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : true])
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872829/3411787