# How to implement Blurred Background Image in Watchkit like TuneIn app

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit

I want to implement the blurred background image in iWatch app. Watchkit.
Many apps like TuneIn implement this.
There are some answers giving adding a blur view but watchkit does not support addsubview.

TuneIn app shows this effect: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunein-radio/id418987775

I want to implement something like this.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check this out....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
//only apply the blur if the user hasn't disabled transparency effects
if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds //view is self.view in a UIViewController
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    //if you have more UIViews on screen, use insertSubview:belowSubview: to place it underneath the lowest view

    //add auto layout constraints so that the blur fills the screen upon rotating device
    blurEffectView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
} else {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Comment: Addsubview is not available in watchkit

Comment: you cannot use UIView in watchkit.

Answer (score 0):

They do this by blurring the image on the phone before sending it over to the Watch.