# Adding UIVisualEffectView to UITableView's background view only works on simulator not device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uivisualeffectview

I have a `UITableView` with a `UIImageView` as the `backgroundView`. This works like a charm. However, now I'm trying to blur this image (using `UIVisualEffectView`) so that the background of the tableView looks blurred. <strike>However, my code somehow ignores the image and simply blurs the white background of the table view. Here is the code:</strike>

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebarImage"]];
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:tempImageView.bounds];
[tempImageView addSubview:blurEffectView];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

EDIT: After some more testing, I found that this works on the simulator, but not on the actual device. I have attached screenshots below a well. What's even more surprising is that when I comment out `[tempImageView addSubview:blurEffectView]`; the image shows up. That means the image is being copied to the phone.

[image: Physical Phone]

[image: Simulator]

Comment: Sorry @Sid I've deleted my answer, of course there something I've been mistaken. If you see correctly on the Sim and not on Device is that possible that the image has a different name? Devices are case sensitive, simulators not

Comment: No problem Andrea, the documentation was a bit blurry on this occasion, quite unlike my backgroundview :). Yes, I've checked the imageName. In fact I set up a sample project with just a UIView and turns out it doesn't work in there either.

Comment: Figured it out Andrea. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has got to be one of the silliest problems I encountered. Apparently, I had "Reduce Transparency" switched on in my iphone settings. Hence the problem. Hope this helps some other poor soul trying to conserve battery.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when "Reduce Transparency" is enabled in iOS 8+ using:

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
   ...
}
```

[This blog post](http://mojoapps.dk/?p=1) goes more in depth on detecting whether `UIVisualEffectView` is available on a device.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebarImage"]];
    UIBlurEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

    UIVisualEffectView * blurEffectView;
    blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];


    blurEffectView.frame = tempImageView.bounds;
    [tempImageView addSubview:blurEffectView];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

[look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview)

Comment: Nope, this code you've posted is functionally identical to what I have above. It does not solve the issue