# Change blurring effect of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationbar, blur

I need to implement a `UINavigationBar` with a custom design, the back image needs to be changed, all the colors need to be changed and the height needs to be changed.

I know all that is possible, but I also need to change the blur effect. It needs to be a lighter blur. Is there a way of doing this without going into private APIs?

Edit: a picture of what it is supposed to look like (I know the status bar is pixelated, ignore it):

[image]

Comment: can u post a sample pic of desired output?

Comment: @Mr.T I have added an example, the standard `UINavigationBar` blur only keeps general areas of color, the top of the bow wouldn't be as clear.

Comment: Use an extra light UIBlurEffect when creating your UIVisualEffectView and apply that to your UINavigationBar

Comment: You can apply a light blur on the background image of the navigation bar until you reach the required effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIVisualEffectView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html) will add translucency and blur effect on iOS 8+ views.

There are three blur [UIBlurEffectStyles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBlurEffectStyle) available.

```
- (void)addBlurEffect{

    CGRect bounds = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark]];
    visualEffectView.frame = bounds;
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:visualEffectView];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:visualEffectView];
}
```

For more information of `UIVisualEffectView`, check this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview).

*************** **EDIT FOR iOS 7** ***************

[Nicklockwood](http://github.com/nicklockwood)'s [FXBlurView](http://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) came into picture for rescue for `iOS5`, `iOS6`, `iOS7`.

I create a [sample project](http://www.dropbox.com/s/0eftwws6zjo0k2e/AnimatedBlurExample.zip?dl=0) for you which has the desired dynamic blur effect on navigation bar for iOS7. Follow the below guide to use into your project.

1. Look into `AppDelegate.m`
2. Here I add the background image to the navigation bar. You can update the image in any viewcontroller to achieve the dynamic blur background image on navigation bar.
3. There are few FXblurview properties like `blurRadius`, `iterations`, `tintColor`; which you must [read here](http://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView?source=c#fxblurview-properties).

Installation Guide:- https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView?source=c#installation

**Full source code** of `FXBlurView-master` can [found here](http://www.dropbox.com/s/d8z6woe76ld18rt/FXBlurView-master%202.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Any backport/workaround for iOS 7? I really need it for my app. I will check (and accept if it works) this answer tonight.

Comment: I am working on sample app, and will edit my answer for ios7 workaround soon. Stay connected.

Comment: @vrwim, I update the answer for iOS7 or lesser OS versions.

Comment: The sample app references a folder outside your project, namely `../../FXBlurView`, could you include it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8z6woe76ld18rt/FXBlurView-master%202.zip?dl=0. I update the answer too.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, as I have successfully used `FXBlurView` to create the blurring effect(using the underlyingview` property), but I'm still running into an issue where the image shown is part of a scrollview, so the blur needs to be calculated fast. On my device it calculates fast, but I'll have to look into ways to do it faster. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad that FXBlurView helped you. For speedy blurring effect, iterations number must be less.