# How to use UIVisualEffectView with a custom subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uivisualeffectview

I looked at this: [How to use UIVisualEffectView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067719/how-to-use-uivisualeffectview) but I don't really understand how to apply it to my situation, after even looking at the comments.

I have a class `SpecialHUD` which is a subclass of `HUDView` which is a subclass of `UIView`. `HUDView` has its layer.contents set to be a background image (certain rectangle with rounded edges), and text in a label added as a subview. I can't change `HUDView`. I only need to change `SpecialHUD`.

I want the background image to act as the thing that blurs whatever is behind it - I can't get rid of the background image.

How do I use the `UIVisualEffectView` with my `SpecialHUD`?

I tried adding this to an update method in my `SpecialHUD`:

```
    UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
    visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

    visualEffectView.frame = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:visualEffectView];
    [[visualEffectView contentView] addSubview:self.label];
```

But it blurs everything in the rectangular container, and disregards the image — I'm not sure how to make everything work together.

Comment: You want the visual effect view to be a subview of the label. That's it.

Comment: I don't think so. The label is a small rectangle within the HUD. If I only applied it to that then the rest of the HUD would still be unblurred, right?

Comment: I misunderstood your code. I was thinking `self` was a view controller.

Comment: What does "disregards the image" mean? It's not blurring the image and it should be?