# iOS - UIImage creating a blurry image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am creating an image with UIImage, and overlaying some text on top.

The end result is coming out blurry, and I want it to be clear

```
UIImage* DrawTextOnImage(NSString *text, UIImage *image)

{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0.0);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 50, image.size.width-20, image.size.height-60);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow.alloc init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraph, NSShadowAttributeName:shadow};

    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:attributes];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

I have seen others having problems when setting the scale wrong, but changing it doesn't affect mine.
Anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17041983/2770572

Comment: That question looks like it wants it to be blurry. I want it to be clear

Comment: Can you post an image? It’s hard to say what the problem is without seeing it.

Comment: Also, why are you adding a shadow with a clear color? Why not just omit the shadow?

Comment: I can't post images as I don't have a reputation higher than 10. I have tried with and without the shadow, it makes no difference. I posted the image here [link](http://i62.tinypic.com/11ift03.jpg)