# Adding blur effect to background in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting a background image to view controller. But also i want to add blur effect to this background. How can I do this?

I am setting background with following code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "testBg")!)
```

I found on internet for blur imageview how can i implement this to my background?

```
var darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
// 2
var blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
blurView.frame = imageView.bounds
// 3
imageView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Comment: Please see here for custom blur scale https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406290/7576100

Answer (score 404, accepted):

I have tested this code and it's working fine:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

For Swift 3.0:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

For Swift 4.0:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Here you can see result:

[image: blurred view]

Or you can use this lib for that:

https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable

Comment: Is there a way to change blur scale? It is too blurry.

Comment: just change `UIBlurEffectStyle.Light`

Comment: Or you can set the alpha on the UIVisualEffectView to less than 1.0. Try 0.8 or 0.7.

Comment: Apple doesn't recommend changing alpha of visualEffectVİew

Comment: @DharmeshKheni how to remove the blur effect to get back the original screen on a button click?

Comment: Just remove `blurEffectView` But didn't tested.

Comment: Where do I place it? I tried to place it in its own UIView class but it just makes a big gray box. What function do I put it in? AwakeFromNib, LayoutSubviews? Neither worked.

Comment: @TolgayToklar could you provide a reference for that? I'd like to read more about it EDIT - Console output: `<UIVisualEffectView> is being asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear broken until opacity returns to 1.`

Comment: It is not blur just a transparent shade.

Comment: all controls are hidden under this blur. Instead addSubview - use self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)

Comment: Thanks, the answer is very clear.
But How can I make the image not clear but at the same time I can recognize what the image describes?

Comment: Please see here for custom blur scale https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406290/7576100

Comment: @TolgayToklar "
Apple doesn't recommend changing alpha of visualEffectVİew" source?

Comment: view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0) for making only the background blur.

Comment: @J.Doe the "Apple doesn't recommend changing the alpha" is here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview specifically `avoid alpha values that are less than 1` ... `Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all.`

Comment: when you change it to `light` style you will see an extra shadow you didn't mention

Answer (score 58):

You can make an extension of UIImageView.

**Swift 2.0**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView
{
    func makeBlurImage(targetImageView:UIImageView?)
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = targetImageView!.bounds

        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        targetImageView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sampleImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 325))
    let sampleImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "ic_120x120")!
    sampleImageView.image =  sampleImage

    //Convert To Blur Image Here
    sampleImageView.makeBlurImage(sampleImageView)

    self.view.addSubview(sampleImageView)
}
```

**Swift 3 Extension**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView
{
    func addBlurEffect()
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds

        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
yourImageView.addBlurEffect()
```

**Addendum:**

```
extension UIView {
  
  /// Remove UIBlurEffect from UIView
  func removeBlurEffect() {
    let blurredEffectViews = self.subviews.filter{$0 is UIVisualEffectView}
    blurredEffectViews.forEach{ blurView in
      blurView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```

Swift 5.0:

```
import UIKit


extension UIImageView {
    func applyBlurEffect() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea! Couldn't it be just makeBlurImage() and then use self instead of targetImageView ?

Comment: I'm not sure but this code may crash if no argument are passed right ? 
This should have a  " if let tmpTargetImageView = targetImageView { }" statement

Comment: @RomOne You would simply get a compile error/failed build if you do not provide an argument. Also, it would work without an image so no need to unwrap that; and testing would show you if you forgot to add an image or not.

Comment: Point is it would crash if a nil ImageView is passed. The ideal is @EmanueleFumagalli 's idea of using self instead of targetImageView, but it is also possible to use a guard statement and return in case of a nil argument.

Comment: its better to give images description too with blurred. well thanks.

Answer (score 15):

**@AlvinGeorge** should just use:

```
extension UIImageView{        
    func blurImage()
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds

        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
}
```

**usage**:

```
 blurredBackground.frame = self.view.bounds
 blurredBackground.blurImage()
 self.view.addSubview(self.blurredBackground)
```

Answer (score 14):

U can also use CoreImage to create blurred image with dark effect

1. Make snapshot for image

   ```
   func snapShotImage() -> UIImage {
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
       if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
           self.layer.renderInContext(context)
           let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
           return image
       }

       return UIImage()
   }
   ```
2. Apply CoreImage Filters as u wish with

   ```
   private func bluredImage(view:UIView, radius:CGFloat = 1) -> UIImage {
   let image = view.snapShotImage()

   if let source = image.CGImage {
       let context = CIContext(options: nil)
       let inputImage = CIImage(CGImage: source)

       let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
       clampFilter?.setDefaults()
       clampFilter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

       if let clampedImage = clampFilter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
           let explosureFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust")
           explosureFilter?.setValue(clampedImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
           explosureFilter?.setValue(-1.0, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)

           if let explosureImage = explosureFilter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
               let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
               filter?.setValue(explosureImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
               filter?.setValue("\(radius)", forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey)

               if let result = filter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
                   let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                   let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, fromRect: bounds)
                   let returnImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
                   return returnImage
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return UIImage()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 12):

**For Swift 3 (iOS 10.0 and 8.0)**

```
var darkBlur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { //iOS 10.0 and above
    darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.prominent)//prominent,regular,extraLight, light, dark
} else { //iOS 8.0 and above
  darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark) //extraLight, light, dark
}
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
blurView.frame = self.view.frame //your view that have any objects
blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurView)
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me on **Swift 5**

```
let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
blurredView.frame = self.view.bounds
backgroundimage.addSubview(blurredView)
```

Comment: Hi @Marta, Do you know how to reduce the capacity of the blurredView?

Answer (score 7):

This one always keeps the right frame:

```
public extension UIView {

    @discardableResult
    public func addBlur(style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .extraLight) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
        let blurBackground = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        addSubview(blurBackground)
        blurBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        blurBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        blurBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        blurBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        return blurBackground
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should always use .dark for style and add the following code to make it look cool

```
    blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .black
    blurEffectView.alpha = 0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

This Code is Working Fine For me!
its for Swift 4.x

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .ExtraLight)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In a UIView extension:

```
func addBlurredBackground(style: UIBlurEffect.Style) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = self.frame
    blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(blurView)
    self.sendSubviewToBack(blurView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way.. I use apple's UIImage+ImageEffects.

```
 UIImage *effectImage = [image applyExtraLightEffect];                        
 self.imageView.image = effectImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
                    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
                    blurEffectView.backgroundColor = .black
                    blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5
                    blurEffectView.frame = topView.bounds
                    if !self.presenting {
                        blurEffectView.frame.origin.x = 0
                    } else {
                        blurEffectView.frame.origin.x = -topView.frame.width
                    }
                    blurEffectView.frame.origin.x = -topView.frame.width
                    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn]) {
                        if !self.presenting {
                            blurEffectView.frame.origin.x = -topView.frame.width
                        } else {
                            blurEffectView.frame.origin.x = 0
                        }
                        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
                    } completion: { (status) in
                        
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Maruta
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334283/16457129 for the answer If anyone else asks, you can reduce the blur effect with the background color of the view.

```html
    func drawBackgroundBlur() {
        backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        // Here, you can increase the alpha value to increase the blur effect
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.05)
        
        let blurredView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        blurredView.frame = backgroundRewardsView.bounds
        blurredView.layer.cornerRadius = 27
        backgroundView.addSubview(blurredView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.7 - blur with custom radius**

Usage example:

```
let view = UIImageView(image: bluredImage(view: superview!, radius: 1.5))
```

Extension:

```swift
extension UIView { 
    func bluredImage(view: UIView, radius: CGFloat = 1) -> UIImage {
        let image = view.snapShotImage()
        
        if let source = image.cgImage {
            let context = CIContext(options: nil)
            let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: source)
            
            let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
            clampFilter?.setDefaults()
            clampFilter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            
            if let clampedImage = clampFilter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
                let explosureFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust")
                explosureFilter?.setValue(clampedImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                explosureFilter?.setValue(-1.0, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)
                
                if let explosureImage = explosureFilter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
                    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
                    filter?.setValue(explosureImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                    filter?.setValue("\(radius)", forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey)
                    
                    if let result = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
                        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: bounds)
                        let returnImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
                        return returnImage
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
    
    private func snapShotImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            self.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image!
        }
        
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```