# Best way to create this effect in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to create this effect for the image in my tableview. Please tell me what is it called and how to apply it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding blur effect to background in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953201/adding-blur-effect-to-background-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Add this to your View Controller

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: self.view.frame)      

visualEffectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)         

self.view.addSubview(visualEffectView)`
```