# blurred background in swift with clear subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect

i want a blurred background. i have a subview for the main view . and i want the subview to not be affected by blur. What should i do?

Code:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds


 let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)
   let vibrancyEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
        vibrancyEffectView.frame = view.bounds

       view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

        view.addSubview(vibrancyEffectView)


        FrameView = UIView()


        if let FrameView = FrameView {

            FrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            FrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
 FrameView.frame=CGRect(x:30,y:(view.frame.height/2-50),width:view.frame.width-60,height:100)
            blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(FrameView)


   }
```

So i want the view to be blurred and the FrameView to be clear.

This is what my app currently looks like.

Comment: do like create one UIView -- add your blurEffectView to that custom UIVIew add your FrameView to mainUIVIewcontroller.view, change the View hirarchy surely works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding blur effect to background in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953201/adding-blur-effect-to-background-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

I had try a test project , and i add the blur to `mainView` first , then i add the `frameView` to `mainView` , i seems good and the `frameView` is not blur.

```
    let mainView = UIImageView.init(frame: self.view.bounds);
    mainView.image = UIImage.init(named: "a.png");
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect.init(style: .dark);
    let effectView = UIVisualEffectView.init(effect: blurEffect);
    effectView.frame = mainView.bounds;
    effectView.alpha = 1;

    let frameView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50));
    frameView.image = UIImage.init(named: "b.png");
    frameView.center = self.view.center;
    //add the blur view first
    mainView.addSubview(effectView);
    self.view.addSubview(mainView);
    self.view.addSubview(frameView);
```

[image]

Comment: @Savitha Suresh Check it

Comment: i have a videopreviewlayer on the main view. how can i do this

Comment: Do you want MainView's videoPlayer be playing when the FrameView exist ? If not , you can screenshot the MainView as a Image and use this function blur it , set it as a imageView back the FrameView , it won't make the FrameView blur.

Comment: ya i want it to be playing

Comment: I had test a project , will it help you ?

Comment: no in the place of an image that u have added as a subview ( ur frameview) , i want a simple rectangle which shows the back image clearly

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the frame upper in you hiearchy, as you see, the BlurEffectView blurs every subview within it, so check that you are adding the subView to the main View of viewController and use func bringSubView to front... :)

Comment: i did it. view.bringSubview(toFront: FrameView) but there is not change. I added the frameview to the main view. view.addSubview(FrameView). I even tried view.insertSubview(blureffectview,at: #someindex) this too didnot work

Comment: are you sure you add the subview to the main View and not the blurred one?

Comment: ya i changed the frameview as subview of main view