# Insert blur layer between two existing view layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UIView with some buttons on it. What I would like to do, is add a full screen blur layer between the UIView and the buttons when the user does a long press on one of them. The visual appearance and location of the buttons shouldn't change.

What is the best way to do this? Also, if possible, I would like to avoid transfering the buttons from one view to another, as this might cause me a lot of trouble (the buttons are draggable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-[UIView insertSubview:belowSubview:]` method to place blur view behind buttons.

I would suggest using Pop animation framework for animations.

As for creating blur view this looks good: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706250/2754158

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. I feel like an idiot now, as the solution was surprisingly simple xD

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view with the blur effect, and use the method `view.insertSubView(blurView, above|belowView: view)`