# Set overlay when dropdown appears on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, overlay

I have a drop down button and when user clicks on it dropdown appears which is a tableview that is hidden.

```
- (IBAction)showDropDown:(id)sender {
    self.tableView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Now i want to set entire screen overlay to 66% just like a blurry screen only excluding button and tableView. They must be visible clearly.  And when user made as selection...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    self.tableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

And everything will be same again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so look here to learn how to make a blurring view

[Creating a blurring overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view)

Now now a blurred View with the entire screen as the frame.

instead of addsubView to make it appear, use

```
[self.View insertSubview:blurredView belowSubView:yourTable];
```

Hope this is helpful..:)

Comment: I wnat to show button too which is just above tableView

Comment: If it is above it eill appear correct since the blur is behind the tableview and the button is above it

Answer (score 0):

To insert overlay view as subview you have to use use UITableViewController instead of UIViewController 
You can insert the overlay below the your table

```
view.insertSubview(view: overlayView, belowSubview: tableView)
```

But this will not overlay the entire screen (navigation bar and status bar is still visible)

To solve this, you have to create a new window

```
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

window.addSubview(yourTableView)

// This will make window above the status bar
window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert

// Set to overlay color
window.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.66)

// Display the window that contains the table view
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```