# Swift iOS - How to make blurred effect that covers TabBarController and NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, effect, blurry

So I have learned to make a blurred effect according to post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view). But that post does not issue how to make a blurred effect that also covers the TabBarController and NavigationController elements.

How can I make a blurred effect that covers the whole screen, including the TabBarController and NavigationController elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you ask right now, which is covering the entire view. That view, however, is of a child `UIViewController`, which has its real estate managed by a parent view controller. Only this parent has its view covering the entire screen. So in the case of embedding in a `UINavigationController`, you'd do instead:

```
blurEffectView.frame = self.navigationController!.view.bounds
self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: Oh, ofc! Perfect Answer! Simple solutions is sometimes difficult to see while you'r still a noob! ;) Ty!