# AVfoundation blur background in Video

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, video-editing

In my application I have fix composition render size of 1280 x 720. So if will import any portrait video then I have to show blur background with fill and aspect frame of video in centre. Same like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCOrqUA0ws4

I achieved to play both videos using `AVMtableComposition`, but I don't know how to blur a particular background track. I did following in my code:

```
self.composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVAsset *firstAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ScreenFlow_Blend" ofType:@"mp4"]]];


[self addAsset:firstAsset toComposition:self.composition withTrackID:1];
[self addAsset:firstAsset toComposition:self.composition withTrackID:2];
//  [self addAsset:ThirdAsset toComposition:self.composition withTrackID:3];

AVAssetTrack *backVideoTrack = [firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo][0];;

self.videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
self.videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 720);
self.videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = [backVideoTrack timeRange];

CGFloat scale = 1280/backVideoTrack.naturalSize.width;
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, 0, -backVideoTrack.naturalSize.height/2 + self.videoComposition.renderSize.height/2);

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *frontLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstruction];
frontLayerInstruction.trackID = 1;
[frontLayerInstruction setTransform:t atTime:kCMTimeZero];

CGFloat scaleSmall = 720/backVideoTrack.naturalSize.height;

CGAffineTransform  translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.videoComposition.renderSize.width/2 - ((backVideoTrack.naturalSize.width/2)*scaleSmall),0);

CGAffineTransform  scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleSmall,scaleSmall);

CGAffineTransform finalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTransform, translate);


CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleSmall,scaleSmall);
t1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t1,1280, 0);

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *backLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstruction];
backLayerInstruction.trackID = 2;
[backLayerInstruction setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];


//    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *maskLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstruction];
//    maskLayerInstruction.trackID = 3;
//    [maskLayerInstruction setTransform:t atTime:kCMTimeZero];


instruction.layerInstructions = @[backLayerInstruction,frontLayerInstruction];

self.videoComposition.instructions = @[ instruction ];

AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:self.composition];
playerItem.videoComposition = self.videoComposition;
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

AVPlayerLayer *newPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[self player]];
[newPlayerLayer setFrame:[[[self playerView] layer] bounds]];
// [newPlayerLayer setHidden:YES];

[[[self playerView] layer] addSublayer:newPlayerLayer];
[self setPlayerLayer:newPlayerLayer];
```

Using above code I can achieve this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2jCvCt5fosyOVNOcGZ1MU1laEU

I know about the `customVideoCompositor` class to filter composition frames. I tried it but if I use `customVideoCompositor` then I am loosing my transformation on composition layers. Plus, from `customVideoCompositor` I don't know how to filter a particular track id.

If someone have any docs link or suggestion then it's really appreciate go forward in this.

Comment: can you show your implementation of `addAsset:toComposition:` and `setPlayerLayer:`?

Comment: what is your video's `backVideoTrack.naturalSize`?

Comment: backVideoTrack,naturalSize is 1920 x 1080

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am facing the same problem @AmritTrivedi

Comment: Does it solved ? Im looking for the solution @Amrit Trivedi

Comment: If someone is still looking for this solution please have look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109092/1140335) for similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVFoundation - Adding blur background to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105717/avfoundation-adding-blur-background-to-video)

Comment: Check this : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105717/avfoundation-adding-blur-background-to-video?answertab=active#tab-top>? hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Before adding the second video layer which is on the centre of the screen, add this code

```
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];//Change the effect which you want.

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

In Swift

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light) //Change the style which suites you
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: I want to play with video tracks. There will be like multiple 5 video tracks. Dynamic blur will be change at runtime for multiple tracks and same thing i want to export at the end as a video. so your solution is only for UI handling blur not for real time video editing.

Comment: You need to check and change the blur effect when you want it, Dynamic blur will be made with your own algorithms which suites your visual effect. See the video link you posted of youtube had a simple blur effect. You want a Dynamic blur, add algorithms make it up.

Answer (score -2):

A way to achieve that is using 2 different `AVPlayer`s and a [a blur overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view): `backgroundLayer` -> `bluer overlay view` -> `frontLayer`. You only need to make sure both player start and stop at the same time.

Another options is using 1 `AVPlayer` and a `time observer`. Extract the current image of the `frontLayer` on every frame, blur it and display in a `backgroundLayer`. The blur function can be found in the same link I provided above.

Comment: Please understand the question. He wants to do it runtime using `AVMutablecomposition`.

Comment: Did you understand his question as well? He asked for any suggestion that can help. And he aslo didn't mention that he want to use only `AVMutablecomposition`.