# PhotoPicker discovery error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ios11

I'm trying to display an image from the photo library in a UIImageView

The full error is:

> 2017-06-09 21:55:59.063307+0200 firstapp2.0[12873:1120778] PhotoPicker
>   discovery error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

My code is included below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    var chosenImage : UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        pic.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
        self.pic!.image = chosenImage as! UIImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any) {        
        self.text.text = "Kreason"
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()    
        imagePicker.delegate = self        
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false    
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it throws the error once I've selected an image. (clicked use image)

From what I can see the failing is when the imagepicker tries to close. 

I'm very new to IOS dev so any help would go a long way, thank you :)

Comment: I got the same error. are you using Xcode 9 beta, iOS 11?

Comment: This used to work... and then iOS 11 Beta 4 gave me this error all of sudden. So weird.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and my implementation is in obj-c. This error message cannot be related to the type casting of the info dictionary returned in the UIImagePicker delegate method in objective-c: `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info`the dictionary values are casted as id in obj-c. 
I've also implemented the authorization request and handling for accessing user's photo library: still getting the error message.
I've added in the info.plist file the privacy entry for user's photo library use.

Comment: I also tried dismissing the image picker in the delegate method by calling dismissViewController on both, the view controller which presented it (which in my case occur to be the also the delegate), and on the UIImagePickerController itself that gets passed to the delegate method.
Still getting this error message, and still getting it either an image gets selected or not.

Comment: I've also tried to keep a strong reference of the image picker instance, but that approach too was still giving the error.
Maybe there is another key to add to the info.plist for aside for "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"?

Comment: I receive current bug however it doesn't prevent me to get image from library and use it later..

Comment: I tried **all** of the suggestions in **all** of the answers combined, to no avail.

Comment: So what does the error message _mean_? What's a "discovery error"?

Answer (score 39):

You need to make explicit Objective-C reference: `@objc`

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    image = chosenImage
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowEditView", sender: self)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Works for me. I had recently updated to Swift 4 and Xcode 9 and this resolved it.

Comment: Works for me. Required after migrating to Swift 4.0.

Comment: Doesn't work. This error occurred after I called `dismiss`.

Comment: Strange.  This worked for me however xcode marks it as a warning and expects a signature of:
`
Instance method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'
Make 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' private to silence this warning
`

Comment: @DarkCastle you need to write the function into a `extension [your class name]` block, outside of the class.

Answer (score 18):

I found this solution. We got this error due to these two reason which is mentioned below.

1. First we need to call this method in for authorization

Authorization Code

```
func checkPermission() {
  let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
    case .authorized: print("Access is granted by user")
    case .notDetermined: PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
      (newStatus) in print("status is \(newStatus)") if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized { / do stuff here */ print("success") }
    })
    case .restricted: / print("User do not have access to photo album.")
    case .denied: / print("User has denied the permission.")
  }
}
```

2. Correct way of method Calling of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

***Wrong:***

```
private func imagePickerController( picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
}
```

Right

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
}
```

I hope this solution will help you out to resolve this error.

If it works for you don't forget to mark it's as a correct, so this will help to other to find the correct way.

Comment: Noob PSA: PHPhotoLibrary is from Swift's Photos module

Comment: Doesn't work. The error happens after I call `picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 17):

I found it!  It is trying to tell you that you do not have authorization to "photos"  You need to include the `#import <Photos/Photos.h>` and request authorization for example like this in Objective-C.

Hope this will save you some time. I spent two full days debugging this!

```
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusDenied");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
            break;
    }
}];
```

I am sure someone can tell you how to do the same in Swift.

Comment: be sure to include  #import <Photos/Photos.h>

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.

Comment: I am getting the below message in console "Reading from private effective user settings. errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
" . It didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 15):

Tried a few of the combination responses without much success.

Using Swift 4, I found that I needed to make sure the following two items were implemented to ensure that the image was selected and placed into the picker (note that the "[discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions:

> Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}"

message still displays in the console, but it does not prevent you from adding an image). Maybe this is a message that results in the picker being dismissed?

1) The delegate for the `UIImagePickerController` is `(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?` so need to explicitly add the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` as one of the protocols:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
    UINavigationControllerDelegate { .... }.
```

2) Make sure that the info.plist has the `Privacy - Photo library Usage Description` key and String value set.

Of course, you need to ensure that you create a `UIImagePickerController` and set its delegate equal to `self` in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate { 
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i have all this in my project.. still it dosen't work

Comment: Thanks i missed setting delegate in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this issue, call function below into viewdidload or viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear to check permission for your app.

```
func checkPermission() {
        let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("Access is granted by user")
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                (newStatus) in
                print("status is \(newStatus)")
                if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                    /* do stuff here */
                    print("success")
                }
            })
            print("It is not determined until now")
        case .restricted:
            // same same
            print("User do not have access to photo album.")
        case .denied:
            // same same
            print("User has denied the permission.")
        }
    }
```

And to use the above method, do not forget to add `import Photos` at top of the class.

Answer (score 11):

**XCODE 10.1 / SWIFT 4.2 :**

1. Add required permissions (others mentioned)
2. Implement this delegate func:

   ```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

       if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
           self.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
           self.imgView.image = pickedImage
       }

       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: True way of using imagePickerController func on Swift 4x

Answer (score 10):

*** Missing DELEGATE *** in Swift 3
In my case, all settings was correct:
1 - Delegates ( UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate );
2 - Permissions already verified;
3 - Plist already done;
4 - Everything read on this Answers, i did;

But i forgot to implement `pickerview.delegate = self` on `viewDidLoad`
Because i COPY and PASTE from my other viewController and forget that!

I hope it help somebody, review your COPY / PASTE first!!!

Comment: Thanks, am struggling for long hours and i have missed "UINavigationControllerDelegate", you saved finally, thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 9):

This might not be the most directly helpful answer - but hopefully it will help!  I'm 99% sure that this particular error message isn't actually pointing you to the real problem.  I spent hours pulling my hair out over this same exact issue.

1) I had authorization for photos printing to the console when I'd launch my picker, 2) I could navigate and pick a photo easy enough, and 3) when I would return me to my view upon dismissing the picker, my button image wasn't updated with the new photo... and the only hint that I had to the problem was the exact same error message that you are receiving.

Turns out I was hard-coding a placeholder image in ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad. Every time the picker was dismissing, it was calling ViewWillAppear and replacing my chosen image with my hard coded image.  I fixed that issue and sure enough - everything is working fine now... and I'm still seeing that error message every time I return from the picker.

I recommend looking somewhere other than the ImagePicker for your problem and you'll likely find it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have not done so, try [this](http://Product%20%3E%20Scheme%20%3E%20Edit%20Scheme%20%3E%20On%20your%20Environment%20Variables%20set%20OS_ACTIVITY_MODE).

> Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Environment Variables `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE: disable`

It solves my issue.

Comment: This suppresses the error messages but doesn't address their cause.  It also suppresses other system messages and anything from `NSLog`.

Comment: This doesn't 'solve' the issue, just makes it invisible. Very bad practice.

Comment: This is the equivalent of hiding your dirt under the rug tbh

Answer (score 7):

I got the same message when I was trying to present another controller from the picker callback `imagePickerController`. The solution which worked for me was to move my code inside the completion callback from the the picker dismiss method

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                let cropController:CropViewController = CropViewController(croppingStyle: .circular, image: pickedImage)
                cropController.delegate = self
                self.present(cropController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, you saved my time 

Comment: Worked wonderfully! Think this is the correct way to deal with the picker errors in Swift 4.x.

Answer (score 6):

This fixes the issue in Swift 4:

Change the code below

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {}
```

to this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {}


Swift 4.2 update:
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){}
```

Comment: My error looked something like this:

errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled} 

And this solved my problem, though I can't speak to if this helps the OP.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are subclassing both: `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Also, remember to set the delegate:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.allowsEditing = true
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
picker.delegate = self  //Don't forget this line!
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Credits to [this source](https://newfivefour.com/swift-ios-choose-an-image-UIImagePickerController.html).

Comment: picker.delegate = self — was my case! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Finding the fix for this problem took me forever. It looks like the problem is that the function imagePickerController of the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate cannot be found. If you have set the delegate correctly and it stopped working after upgrading to Swift 4, the problem is probably that you didn't make it accessible to Objective-C by using @objc which is required since Swift 4.

It has to be:

> @objc func imagePickerController(...

instead of

```
func imagePickerController(...
```

Comment: It creates error `Objective-C method 'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:' provided by method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'`

Comment: Exactly, this is the way to fix it!

Comment: @NicoNeill did you add the function into an `extension` block?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by setting 1 second delay when setting image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        picker.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
            self.discussionImage.image = image
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add `internal func` at the beginning and then add the lower case after the parenthesis (`_ picker: UIImagePickerController…` and then change from `AnyObject` to `Any`]…
Check code below:

```
internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        userPhoto.image = pickedImage

    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This had me stumped, but the answer at the link below worked for me. Error is gone and image displays as expected

Like one of the answers above, you have to have `(_ picker...` but also `@objc` before the function.

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
...
}
```

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82105

Answer (score 2):

This solved my error :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    addPhotoBtn.setImage(pickedImage, for: .normal)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check by steps as follow:

1. Import Photos
2. Has access to album:

   ```
   func authorizeToAlbum(completion:@escaping (Bool)->Void) {

   if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
       NSLog("Will request authorization")
       PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status) in
           if status == .authorized {
               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   completion(true)
               })
           } else {
               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   completion(false)
               })
           }
       })

   } else {
       DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
           completion(true)
       })
   }
   }
   ```
3. Present UIImagePickerController

   ```
   self.authorizeToAlbum { (authorized) in
       if authorized == true {
           let picker = UIImagePickerController()
           picker.delegate = self
           picker.allowsEditing = false
           picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

           self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
   ```
4. **The key step, make sure the delegate method is like following strictly**

   ```
   // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
       self.pickedImage = pickedImage
       if let finalImage = handleImage(originalImage: self.pickedImage!, maskImage: self.maskImage!) {
           self.imageView.image = finalImage
       }
   }

   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and it solved my issue.

- add @objc
- add internal
- add _ before imagePicker
- make sure you are using Any and not AnyObject

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, `internal` is the default; I wonder what difference it makes to specify it...

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was getting this error because I was presenting an image picker controller without first verifying if the user had allowed access to images. Elsewhere in my code the user had granted permission so I think all I needed to do was import Photos. However, since they 'may' not have granted permission at that point in the app adding this just before I presented the image picker controller solved the issue for me (import Photos as well).

```
// request photos permission if permission has not been granted
    if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in

        })
    }
```

If this answer seems redundant my apologies but I had to piece together from a few different answer to get my solution working. Perhaps this will help someone else using Swift 4.

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

Answer (score 2):

This "Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13" error has confounded a lot of people even though it seems to be a harmless apple debug message. I was having trouble getting the image I picked to set in my UI and thought that that error was the problem however it was something a bit more subtle.

I have my image picker controller in a file separate from the view controller that's presenting it.

**MyViewController.swift**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

    ...
}

extension MyViewController: ImagePickerDelegate {
    func didSelect(image: UIImage?) {
        self.profileImage.image = image
    }
}
```

**ImagePicker.swift**

```
open class ImagePicker: NSObject {
    ...
    private func pickerController(_ controller: UIImagePickerController, didSelect image: UIImage?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {self.delegate?.didSelect(image: image)}
        )
    }
}
```

Most of the tutorials and answers have the completion set to nil. However if you set the completion to nil and call the delegate's didSelect method separately, the method gets called but the image doesn't set so make sure to use dismiss' completion.

And again, I know this answer might not be directly related to the original question but I have a feeling a lot of people are coming here for this issue and the given solutions aren't helping. The reason is that most of the people giving answers have their image picker controller in the same class as their main view controller and thus not needing to use a completion.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Error also happens when you **have not configured the permissions of the usage of the Photo Library** in you `Info.plist` file.

You need to add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` in the `Info.plist` with a *String* that will appear when your App tries the first time to access the Photo Library of the User.

The final `Info.plist` adjustments should look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error and I fixed it in this way:

get image object in different way depends on UIImagePickerController allowsEditing is true or false

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if isImagePickerAllowEditing {
        sourceImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    } else {
        sourceImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    ....

}
```

And of course, ask the permission to access photo library first as above comments.

Answer (score 1):

On my end `UINavigationControllerDelegate` delegate is missing.

`class YourViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

In my case as swift allocation memory management seems to be optimised and fixed by Apple Team.
My code was perfectly working till a swift update and I found my "mistake" was that I wasn't retaining the picker but It has been working for ages without the retention so here a full ready to work solution.

```
// Add Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description to your info.plist
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>APPNAME need to access your pictures to violate your privacy :P</string>
```

And

```
import Photos    
class MyImageSelector: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var picker = UIImagePickerController() 
    // Make sure to retain this picker var until the picker returned

    func checkPermission() {
        let call = self.presentAuthorized

            let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:
                print("Access is granted by user")
                showPicker()
            case .notDetermined:
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ newStatus in
                print("status is \(newStatus)")
                if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                    /* do stuff here */
                    print("success")
                    showPicker()
                }
                })
            case .restricted:
                print("User do not have access to photo album.")
            case .denied:
                print("User has denied the permission.")
            }

    }

    func showPicker() {
        picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self  //Don't forget this line!
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // DO something with picture
    }

    @objc public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // User cancelled the pick
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. None of the above mentioned suggestions worked for me. However, I resolved it, by explicilty calling the picker.dismiss and dismiss post that. I am not clear why I have make dismiss calls like that, but it worked for me.

```
   @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        print("Image picked")
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        dismiss(animated: true) {
            print("dismissed")
             self.delegate?.presentEditor(img: (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!, id: self.id!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the all these answers and little bit modified here and not needed to dismiss, this worked for me, Thanks others who have replied here.

```
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

      print("########### media picked")
      picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      let img = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage)!
      //set img -picked image to "profileImage" UIimageView
      //use image here
       self.profileImage.image = img
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of IMage PickerView.....

```
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


  @IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {

        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print(info)

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage
        {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage as! UIImage


        }else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{

            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage as! UIImage


        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if var selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker
        {
            myImageView.image = selectedImage
        }

    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**click on imageView to load image from photo library and show preview on same imageview. on swift 4**

```
 let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView! 

     override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                 imagePicker.delegate = self
                let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignUpViewController.click))
                userImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
                userImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            }

            @objc func click()
            {
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
                imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }


            @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
                if  let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
                userImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                userImage.image = chosenImage
                }
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue on **Swift 4.2** and **Xcode 10.0**. Although the image picker was working correctly Xcode showed this error on console. To get rid of this:

- On Xcode menu Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme
- Select 'Run' tab, then 'Arguments'
- On 'Environment Variables' section add a variable with Name **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** and Value **disable**

Comment: Well ...not really...for me it shows this error but the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method is not called...so I needed to enable this value in order to see this error

Answer (score 0):

Use didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as! UIImage
        userProfileImage.image = chosenImage

        uploadImage(chosenImage)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 and Above:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!

    var chosenImage : UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pic.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        dismiss(animated: true)
        chosenImage = image
        **pic.image = chosenImage**

    }

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any) {
        self.text.text = "Kreason"
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        //imagePicker.dataSource = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to make UIImagePickerController inside method but to make 
it as a class variable and to create it only once.

I had the same issue as you when I forgot to set a delegate to UIImagePickerController

Answer (score -3):

The solution that worked for me was simply going into Product (at the top of the screen) -> Scheme -> EditScheme -> Arguments

In Environment Variables, add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE with a value of "disable"

Hopefully this works for someone else!

I'll attach a screenshot just in case my description seemed confusing[image]

Comment: This only disables a lot of alerts and NSLog outputs; it doesn't actively solve the problem (unless it is a bug in xcode in itself).

Comment: You just said it disables a lot of alerts correct? Isn't that the purpose?

Comment: It disables the alert, but doesn't fix the problem(s).

It depends what you're searching for. *shrug*