# Create firebase chat demo: I want to upload user image but its give an error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4

errors encountered while discovering extensions:

> Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled} 2017-10-03
>   11:08:38.585084+0530 NewChatDemo[858:20663] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Here is my **Swift 4** code:

```
@objc func handleRegister()
{
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else{
        print("invalid form")

        return
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: User? , error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else{
            return
        }

        //successfully authenticated user
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImageView.image!){
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print(error)
                }
                else
                {
                    print(metadata)
                }
            })
        }

        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://newchatapp-470cb.firebaseio.com/")

        let uerReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)

        let values = ["name": name, "email": email]

        uerReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil
            {
                print(err)
                return
            }

            print("Successfully saved user in firebase db")
        })

    })
}

@objc func handleSelectProfileImageView()
{
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print(info)

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage
    {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage as! UIImage


    }else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{

        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage as! UIImage


    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if var selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker
    {
        profileImageView.image = selectedImage
    }

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("Cancel picker")


}
```

Comment: Where is the call for, handleRegister() ?

Comment: @objc func handleLoginRegister()
    {
        if loginRegistrationSegmentedControll.selectedSegmentIndex == 0
        {
            
            handleLogin()
        }
        else
        {
            handleRegister()
            
        }
    }

Comment: when i select image and dismiss image picker its give an error "encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465904/photopicker-discovery-error-error-domain-pluginkit-code-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is due to this line:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
```

You need to give the name of the file that you want to upload ,so you can do something like this:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("yourImageName.png")
```