# Thumbnail from UiImagepicker video

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I picked a video from album using `UIImagePickerController` and trying to generate thumbnail from it using below function:

```
func getThumbnailFrom(path: URL) -> UIImage? {

        do {

            let asset = AVURLAsset.init(url: path)
            print(asset.url)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

            return thumbnail

        } catch let error {

            print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil

        }

    }
```

But on logs I van see `*** Error generating thumbnail: Cannot Open`

```
[discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
```

Any idea why ? Its the bug in iOS 11 devices, any idea how to fix this issue and generate thumbnail ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465904/photopicker-discovery-error-error-domain-pluginkit-code-13

Comment: Already tried everything, thanks @AmitBattan

Comment: I think you have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562336/photopicker-fb-grapsharer-issues-in-ios-11 Maybe you can follow it

Comment: @JimmyJames that was asked by me only. And that is fixed just by adding additional usage description.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is about asking permissions which I already asked at the beginning of my app. Still I need to ask again, I dont know why, but it worked.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
            ()

            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                print("creating 2")
                if let thumbnailImage = self.getThumbnailFrom(path: self.facebookVideoURL){
                    self.thumbnailImageForVideo.image = thumbnailImage
                }
            }

        })
```