# IOS FacebookShare Error 'reserved' being returned

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-share

I've tried searching but could not find an answer. I have written an app and I am trying to share content to facebook. Basically I would like to share a URL and maybe a quote or title.

I keep getting an error called 'reserved' but I am not sure what it means or how to fix it. Any help would be great!

```
func fbClick() {

    let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "www.google.com")!)
    showShareDialog(content, mode: .native)

}

func showShareDialog<C: ContentProtocol> (_ content: C, mode: ShareDialogMode = .automatic) {
    let dialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
    dialog.presentingViewController = self
    dialog.mode = mode

    do {
        try dialog.show()
    } catch (let error) {
        self.view.makeToast("Invalid share content. Failed to present share dialog with error \(error)", duration: 3.0, position: .top)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

This line...

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "www.google.com")!)
```

Should have been like this...

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")! as URL)
```

or like this

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")! as URL, quote: quote)
```

Comment: Just a note: I have the same "reserved" error using a VideoShareContent and a valid already-defined URL object. I tried your NSURL solution but it is the same. So this answer does not explain what is that "reserved" error.

Comment: I still didn't know at the time but I know a little more now. It means the content isn't correct. I think it's like trying to do math on a string. I haven't done much with the VideoShareContent but I would try multiple video formats. I'm pretty sure the VideoShareContent whats a Url of some local location like in memory and not a website URL. I say that just in case you thought it was.

Comment: As an additional info, I went further the « reserved » error by adding my video the photo/vidéo gallery, fetch back the new URL (from gallery) and Messenger (or Facebook ) open ended

Comment: But the video did not load inside messenger (only a white box instead of a thumbnail) and gave me an error (check internet connection... LOL) when I tried to send it.

Comment: @ddp try changing the mode. It may be the way it’s presenting.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same `reserved` error but while using `VideoShareContent`. Spent 5 hours to find the issue and finally found. Really hope someone finds this helpful too.

**Solution**: when you are retrieving the `url` of your video from `info` param from the `UIImagePickerController` delegate method make sure you use the key `"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"`.

Example:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    if let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL {
        let video = Video(url: videoURL)
        let content = VideoShareContent(video: video)
        do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: self, content: content)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional info**: initially I **did not** use this key "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL". Why: it's [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerreferenceurl?language=objc). According to Apple, you should use UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset instead. But the url from there also returns `reserved` error. Another try was to use key `"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"`, but it also didn't succeed.