# I get a error with my imagePickerViewController in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photos, userdefaults

I get this error when calling my delegate method for my ImagepickerViewController

> Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

My delegate method is

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
         UserDefaults.standard.set(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), forKey: "avatarImage")
    }
    else
    {
        //Error message
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> Edit: I tried the other questions answers, and they did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhotoPicker discovery error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465904/photopicker-discovery-error-error-domain-pluginkit-code-13)

Comment: Do not store image data in UserDefaults. Write the image to a file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an `@objc` and make explicit Objective-C reference:

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
```