# Unable to upload image using photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, gallery

I am getting this error after choosig image from gallery in ios app
errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

I have also added- Privacy- Photo Library photo description, camera description.

Also tried- OS_ACTIVITY_MODE  disable

but still unable to fix

Comment: Code is required while asking question , also add your attempts to fix issue

Comment: -(void)selectImage
{
    
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    
    
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
//uploading image from gallery but after chosing image and click on choose,getting above error

Comment: I found this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465904/photopicker-discovery-error-error-domain-pluginkit-code-13

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you are using but one of the problems might be that you are not properly handling all the authorisation cases.

```
func performPermissionCheck() {
    let authorisationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() 

    switch authorisationStatus {
        case .authorized: 
             print("Access granted")
        case .notDetermined: 
             PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ newStatus in 
              if newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized { 
                  print("success")}
            })
        case .restricted: 
             print("No access to album")
        case .denied: 
             print("Permission Denied")
   }
}
```