# I'm trying to display an image from the photo library in a UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, ios12

The full error is:

> 2018-11-17 11:48:21.587818-0700 TestApp[3763:162426] [discovery]
>   errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

My code:

```
import UIKit

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var captionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
var selectedImage: UIImage?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesturn = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSelectPhoto))
    photo.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturn)
    photo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

@objc func handleSelectPhoto() {
    let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func shareButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

}
}
 extension CameraViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("did Finish Picking Media")
    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
        selectedImage = image
        photo.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhotoPicker discovery error: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465904/photopicker-discovery-error-error-domain-pluginkit-code-13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using string `"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"` as key for info dictionary use info key for original image `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage`

So replace this

```
if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
```

with this

```
if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
```

also replace info dictionary type in parameters of delegate method from  `[String : Any]` to `[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]`

```
imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

and last replace `private` keyword before delegate method with `@objc`

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Comment: @Bose try edited answer. You have to also change delegate method info parameter