# Advance Video Effects and Transition in IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation, video-editing

I know editing features in avfoundation for merging videos, trimming video and run time video effects through glview and post process using avexport session. I made one video editing app also with lot of cool features - Video Movie Editor- A Music Maker For Insta.gram by Dynamite Standard, LLC
https://appsto.re/gb/hSe4_.i

But now we want to go ahead like VivaVideo app with cool transitions in video with effects
VivaVideo - Video Editor & Photo Movie Maker by QuVideo Inc.
https://appsto.re/gb/e8QcS.i

I tried with avcustomcompositor class to filter or process each frame using core image but it's not working smoothly  and crashes even in iPhone 6s with blur + mask effects. 
I don't know about opengl but i am ready to learn it, but specific to video editing , so viva video app uses opengl to render and giving effects to video??
One of my friend said that they are using .xp file like json and they got all transformation values from it for each theme.

So anybody will guide me how to achieve that kind of effects? In google i only see in suggestion of GPUImage and that libray is great but not fitting with my requirements.

In past i asked question like show video with it's aspect frame And show blur frame of that video in background but i didn't receive any answer of it. That's the first basic step to start this. 
[AVfoundation blur background in Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313688/avfoundation-blur-background-in-video)

Comment: My Question has only one point - How to make VideoEffects like ViVa Video? I don't want silly answers that's why given specific details that how much I know. Since 2 years I seen that one specific video editing community not sharing knowledge. and that's why monopoly of apps like Viva video in store. And now my question put on hold, Please re consider to open this.

Comment: Yes you are right, it’s monopoly, Never seen answers on Advance video editing and i have also follow your reverse video question earlier, I was supposed to do that but no help from community.

Comment: Don't be aggressive but some where you are right. We are also looking for these kind of solutions but no help till now.