# How are nested blurred backgrounds achieved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiblureffect

I have encountered a problem. The app needs to achieve the effect show in the following figure; Blur with a nested blur.
Please provide some advice, thank you very much.

[image: The effect of iOS]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view try this.

Comment: Use UIVisualEffectView to implement this.