# Adding blurred background image

Tags: ios, background-image

Is there another method to add blurred background for a popup without using imageview and taking snapshot of the previous window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a blurring overlay view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy.

All you need is a "visual effect view with blur and vibrancy" view.
You can add it directly from the Object Library. Just Drag and drop the view. You can set the background colour to clear if needed, And you can set the blur level to light, extra light etc.... Just go through those stuffs

Answer (score 1):

To add blur view you can use UIBlurEffect.There are 3-4 blur style your can choose from. You can also change alpha of this blur effect in ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 to achieve more accurate blur for your image

**To add Blur effect**
- You can use like view.addBlurEffect

```
func addBlurEffect() {

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.extraLight)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.4
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
```

**To Remove blur You can use** 
- To remove blur from UIView view.removeBlurView

```
 func removeBlurView(blurView:UIView){
            for subview in blurView.subviews {
                if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
                    subview.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at `UIVisualEffectView` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIVisualEffectView` like below

```
var blurView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
blurView.frame = view.bounds
blurView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
popUpView.addSubview(blurView)
```