# How to blur an existing image in a UIImageView with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cifilter, ciimage

The setup is simple.

- A ViewController with UIImageView that has an image assigned.
- A UIButton that when clicked blurs the image in the UIImageView.

[image: Storyboard]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bg: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func blur(_ sender: Any) {
        let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: (bg.image?.cgImage)!)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        filter?.setValue(10, forKey: "inputRadius")
        let blurred = filter?.outputImage
        bg.image = UIImage(ciImage: blurred!)
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked the screen just turns white. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator? Some CI filters (I'm working on a masked blur right now) have pitiful performance (think in terms of taking a minute to display) in the simulator.

Comment: Please check my answer with Github link to test..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could simply use `UIVisualEffect` to achieve blur effect. As you trying to achieve a blur effect using CoreImage.Try below code after `import CoreImage` to your class.

```
var context = CIContext(options: nil)

func blurEffect() {

    let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") 
    let beginImage = CIImage(image: bg.image!)
    currentFilter!.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    currentFilter!.setValue(10, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
    cropFilter!.setValue(currentFilter!.outputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    cropFilter!.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: beginImage!.extent), forKey: "inputRectangle")

    let output = cropFilter!.outputImage 
    let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
    bg.image = processedImage
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** I recommend you to test the code in real device as Simulator performance is too slow on coreImage.

Comment: This worked great. I didn't want to use `UIVisualEffect` because I wanted to control the level of blur with the inputRadius. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMoeykens Please see here for custom blur scale https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406290/7576100

Comment: blur with specific blur value https://gist.github.com/afshin-hoseini/9c370268ffa4c43b0696

Comment: Tried all other blurring suggestions and this worked perfectly! The other attempts I used always cropped the image in a strange way.. the crop filter fixed that, thanks!

Comment: Modified the code to maintain the original scale and orientation. Without that modification, if the original was a rotated image the blurred image would be rotated with respect to the original.

Answer (score 32):

for those who ❤️ protocols

```
protocol Blurable {
    func addBlur(_ alpha: CGFloat)
}

extension Blurable where Self: UIView {
    func addBlur(_ alpha: CGFloat = 0.5) {
        // create effect
        let effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
        
        // set boundry and alpha
        effectView.frame = self.bounds
        effectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        effectView.alpha = alpha
        
        self.addSubview(effectView)
    }
}

// Conformance
extension UIView: Blurable {}

// use
someImageview.addBlur()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one nit: 'protocol Blurable', a bit better naming I believe :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I got my expected result in SWIFT 3.1:
Hope it will help.

```
func blurImage(image:UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: image)
        let originalOrientation = image.imageOrientation
        let originalScale = image.scale

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey) 
        let outputImage = filter?.outputImage

        var cgImage:CGImage?

        if let asd = outputImage
        {
            cgImage = context.createCGImage(asd, from: (inputImage?.extent)!)
        }

        if let cgImageA = cgImage
        {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImageA, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Comment: good answer, I upvoted, but please follow a Code Style writing your code. For instance what is this: `asd` or `cgImageA`. You can simply write: `if let outputImage = outputImage { // }`. For more info check raywenderlich code Style I use: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#optionals

Comment: Works but it is slow

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a handy implementation right in CoreImage
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1645897-applyinggaussianblur

```
extension UIImage {

func blur(_ radius: Double) -> UIImage? {
    if let img = CIImage(image: self) {
        return UIImage(ciImage: img.applyingGaussianBlur(sigma: radius)).cropped(to: img.extent)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This almost works but it changes the image size/position, be sure to crop the img afterwards.
img.applyingGaussianBlur(sigma: radius).cropped(to: img.extent)

Comment: You could have edited the answer. I just did. :)

Comment: @VictorEngel thank you :) sorry I didnt keep track on this

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var bgImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var blurButton: UIButton!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        @IBAction func blurButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

                let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: (self.bgImageView.image?.cgImage)!)
                let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
                filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
                filter?.setValue(10, forKey: "inputRadius")
                let blurred = filter?.outputImage

                var newImageSize: CGRect = (blurred?.extent)!
                newImageSize.origin.x += (newImageSize.size.width - (self.bgImageView.image?.size.width)!) / 2
                newImageSize.origin.y += (newImageSize.size.height - (self.bgImageView.image?.size.height)!) / 2
                newImageSize.size = (self.bgImageView.image?.size)!

                let resultImage: CIImage = filter?.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
                let context: CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
                let cgimg: CGImage = context.createCGImage(resultImage, from: newImageSize)!
                let blurredImage: UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgimg)
                self.bgImageView.image = blurredImage
        }

    }
```

### Output:

[image]

### Gitbub link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/ImageBlurEffect

Answer (score 2):

A good performing solution with decent results is `StackBlur` which uses a clever  algorithm that efficiently approximates a blur:

> This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur It creates
>   much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is 7x faster than my
>   Gaussian Blur implementation. I called it Stack Blur because this
>   describes best how this filter works internally: it creates a kind of
>   moving stack (or maybe a "Tower of Hanoi" kind of structure) of colors
>   whilst scanning through the image. This "tower" controls the weights
>   of the single pixels within the convolution kernel and gives the pixel
>   in the center the highest weight. The secret of the speed is that the
>   algorithm just has to add one new pixel to the right side of the stack
>   and at the same time remove the leftmost pixel. The remaining colors
>   on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on or reduced by
>   one, depending on if they are on the right or on the left side of the
>   stack.

Check out [StackBlur on Github](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS).

There are many versions out there, also Swift ports, but those are considerable slower than the Obj-C versions.

#### Addition 2019:

If the images to blur are remotely loaded, I can highly recommend the [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) framework that remotely loads images and can apply a blur filter out of the box. It's application is comparable to the Glide library on Android. While blurring one image may be easy, blurring many images - like in a collection view - while considering device resource constraints is less trivial. Nuke is highly optimized for remote image loading, caching and processing. It is also extendable in several aspects. From comparing available remote image loading frameworks, I think that Nuke is the most stable and most advanced for that purpose as of Nov 2019.

Answer (score 1):

my extension

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func blurImage(radius: CGFloat = 10) -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        let inputCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        let outputImage = filter?.outputImage
        
        if let outputImage = outputImage,
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: inputImage.extent) {
            
            return UIImage(
                cgImage: cgImage,
                scale: scale,
                orientation: imageOrientation
            )
        }
        return nil
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the blur in a NSObject class, so I can use this method in whole project easily.

```
class Helper: NSObject
{
    class func addBlurView(_ inView : UIView) -> UIVisualEffectView
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        //always fill the view
        blurEffectView.frame = inView.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5

        return blurEffectView
    }
}
```

In ViewController I made object of **UIVisualEffectView**. Then call the helper class method of to add blur.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   var blurEffectView : UIVisualEffectView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      blurEffectView = Helper.addBlurView((imgView)!)
      self.imgView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if something is coming nil. I had a similar issue, but in my case I wasn't creating a new instance of CIImage, because of that image.ciimage was coming nil.

Answer (score -1):

You can add blur effect by `UIBlurEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView`:

```
@IBAction func blur(_ sender: Any) {

    let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark) 
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
    blurView.frame = bg_imagview.bounds
    blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    bg_imagview.addSubview(blurView)

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey to all the LAZY guys just like me.

Just add SwifterSwift with cocoapods.

Import SwifterSwift.

```
import SwifterSwift
```

Blur your image view just like below.

```
someImageView.blur()
```