# How blur a image in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, blur, core-image

I know we can use `UIBlurEffect` to show user a blurred image with the following code, but **how to only get a blurred image** (layer is better)?

```
 let baseView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gScreenWidth, height: 90))

 let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: gScreenWidth, height: 90))
 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style:  .light)
 let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
 blurView.frame = backgroundImageView.frame

 baseView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
 baseView.addSubview(blurView)
```

Comment: move this line blurView.frame = backgroundImageView.frame to the `viewDidLayoutSubViews` method

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you. I just mentioned it as a `UIBlurEffect` example.

Comment: If a `UIBlurEffect` isn't working well enough for you, use CoreImage. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW29

Comment: I don't know what yo uare exactly asking, but whenever you need something more, use CoreImage.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156542/how-to-blur-an-existing-image-in-a-uiimageview-with-swift/41157042#41157042