# How to add blur effect like image downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

I am making a chat application and want to add a blur effect like image downloading similar to whatsapp as I also try the UIVisualEffectView but does not reach to the similar effect and also try to reduce the alpha of UIVisualEffectView but does not reach near to this effect.Can any one tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

[image: I want this effect]

I try using UIVisual effectView but can not reach the same one

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with whasApp, does the image initially start blur'd or does the image appear once the user attempts to download the image from the message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view

Comment: @Mukul what you want is to use interlaced image?. Here is a good article explaining it https://blog.codinghorror.com/progressive-image-rendering/       and you will probably need some third party control or your own coding if you can implement it.

Comment: try using [this](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.BlurView) or [this](https://github.com/NZN/UIImage-Helpers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any third party library like  https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Create blurred image using this and add it to your cell on the specific event.

Or you can use following method from Apple:

```
// This method is taken from Apple's UIImageEffects category provided in WWDC 2013 sample code

- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    // Check pre-conditions.
    if (self.size.width < 1 || self.size.height < 1) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: invalid size: (%.2f x %.2f). Both dimensions must be >= 1: %@", self.size.width, self.size.height, self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!self.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: %@", self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (maskImage && !maskImage.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: %@", maskImage);
        return nil;
    }

    CGRect imageRect = { CGPointZero, self.size };
    UIImage *effectImage = self;

    BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    BOOL hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.) > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    if (hasBlur || hasSaturationChange) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(effectInContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(effectInContext, 0, -self.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(effectInContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

        vImage_Buffer effectInBuffer;
        effectInBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;
        effectOutBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectOutContext);

        if (hasBlur) {
            // A description of how to compute the box kernel width from the Gaussian
            // radius (aka standard deviation) appears in the SVG spec:
            // http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement
            //
            // For larger values of 's' (s >= 2.0), an approximation can be used: Three
            // successive box-blurs build a piece-wise quadratic convolution kernel, which
            // approximates the Gaussian kernel to within roughly 3%.
            //
            // let d = floor(s * 3*sqrt(2*pi)/4 + 0.5)
            //
            // ... if d is odd, use three box-blurs of size 'd', centered on the output pixel.
            //
            CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            NSUInteger radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if (radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
            }

            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (uint32_t) radius, (uint32_t) radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (uint32_t) radius, (uint32_t) radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, (uint32_t) radius, (uint32_t) radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
        }
        BOOL effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = NO;
        if (hasSaturationChange) {
            CGFloat s = saturationDeltaFactor;
            CGFloat floatingPointSaturationMatrix[] = {
                0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                0,                    0,                    0,  1,
            };
            const int32_t divisor = 256;
            NSUInteger matrixSize = sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix)/sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[0]);
            int16_t saturationMatrix[matrixSize];
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
                saturationMatrix[i] = (int16_t)roundf(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor);
            }
            if (hasBlur) {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
                effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = YES;
            }
            else {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
            }
        }
        if (!effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if (effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    // Set up output context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.size.height);

    // Draw base image.
    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

    // Draw effect image.
    if (hasBlur) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        if (maskImage) {
            CGContextClipToMask(outputContext, imageRect, maskImage.CGImage);
        }
        CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, effectImage.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Add in color tint.
    if (tintColor) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // Output image is ready.
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}

//Usage:
[imageToBlur applyBlurWithRadius:2.0f tintColor:[UIColor clearColor] saturationDeltaFactor:1.0 maskImage:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create this view by adding blureffect view on imageview. But this will work when image is showing in imageview.

```
  let effect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light))
  effect.frame = imageView.frame    
  imageView.addSubview(effect)
```

Comment: I try using this but couldn't reach the same effect.

Comment: try to add this code to I am able to generate blur effect with this code effect.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
+(UIImage *)coreBlurImage:(UIImage *)image
           withBlurNumber:(CGFloat)blur {
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage  *inputImage=[CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:@(blur) forKey: @"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *result=[filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CGImageRef outImage=[context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
    UIImage *blurImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:outImage];
    CGImageRelease(outImage);
    return blurImage;
}
```