# Programmatically blur background view behind Pop Over

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, uivisualeffectview

I have a view controller(PopOverViewController) being instantiated by another view controller(ListViewController).

***Within* *ListViewController*, PopOverViewController is modally presented:**

```
popOverVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController

popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

***Within* *PopOverViewController*, the PopOverViewController is animated in/out with CGAfflineTransformation:**

```
    func showAnimate()
{
    self.shadowView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.shadowView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
    });
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.shadowView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    }, completion:{(finished: Bool) in
        if (finished)
        {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}
```

***In the viewDidLoad of the PopOverViewController*, the background color is turned down:**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
```

**My Question:**
When the PopOver is presented, the background is still visible due to the alpha of the PopOver. I would like to blur this background when the PopOver is being presented, and have the blur disappear when the PopOver is closed.

I am stumped on how to do this.

Thank you!

Swift 3

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706250/4008175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a blurring overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view)

Comment: @AppDevGuy Thank you for linking this. I will give it a try.

Comment: @AppDevGuy The blur works, however it covers the entire screen rather than the background (behind the Pop Over).

Comment: do `yourPopOverView.sendToBack( your blur view )` which will place it in background of the popup

Comment: @AppDevGuy Not working. It's still blurring the entire view. Would we be able to continue this in chat? Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146120/discussion-between-app-dev-guy-and-miles).

Comment: @AppDevGuy Hello, I ran into a small problem with the animation of the blur view. When the Pop Over fades in, the blur view "snaps" into full opacity, rather than fade in with the pop over. I've tried adjusting the alpha settings for the "showAnimate()", but it doesn't seem to be fixing this. I can send a video over that depicts it if you'd like? Thank you.

Comment: I have messaged in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

```
private func makeEffectView() {
        let effect: UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
        effectView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        self.window?.addSubview(effectView)
    }



private func removeEffectView() {
        if effectView != nil {
            self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```