# iOS7 Realtime Blur (without Toolbar Workaround)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, blur

I have found a couple of RealTime Blur Libraries.

But all of them use the "toolbar workaround" to do the blur on iOS7.

**Since Apple started to reject apps using this workaround I was wondering which library I could use to do a realtime blur on a UIView?**

Comment: Have you tried using the `CoreImage` [`CIGaussianBlur`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGaussianBlur) filter?

Comment: I need all the "blur all UI elements in the background" magic.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036655/ios-7-style-blur-view