# iOS, how to add a blur effect to a background view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to add a blur effect to a background view.

Here's my background view.
https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController/blob/master/Source/MJPopupBackgroundView.m

I believe that the idea is to take a snapshot of the parent view and then add a blur effect to that image.

I've seen various approaches not sure what will work and what is the best approach.

Also I'm not sure where I'd create the snapshot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 style Blur view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036655/ios-7-style-blur-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way is indeed probably just to take a snapshot and blur that.

You can take a snapshot by doing something like this:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0f);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Keep in mind this is a fast iOS7+ blurring method so if you want to support lower versions of iOS you will need to use a slower method, [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display/22494886#22494886).

There are a lot of ways to achieve blur, the 2 most popular are probably to use Apple's `UIImageEffects` WWDC sample code which [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/timshadel/657da67d43cfb1ea4acc), or to use `GPUImage`, which [can be found here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Comment: Thanks, where would I put / call that function?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want (most likely place would be a `UIImage` category). You call it when you want to get a snapshot of some view (probably when you are about to put an overlay on top of it).

Answer (score 0):

Ablow link points to present view and affect the background with blur effect

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52374977/5233180

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer, or possibly a duplicate flag for the question you linked

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I haven't enough reputation to add a comment now  when I have it I will make it as a comment after I have it