# iOS, native blur view effects available from iOS9+?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to show a view / popup (a dialog), however I need a blur effect in the background and support iOS 9+.

Are they blur operations provided natively in UIKit which will support rotation?

I'm concerned that the blur effect will work off a screenshot and once I've shown my dialog and the screen rotates it won't be possible to add a blur effect to the screenshot image.

Perhaps there are other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKIt has a UIVisualEffectView to add the beautiful blur effects

- from the object library  drag a UIVisualEffectView and drop it on the view that needs make it blur for your case (background)

declare these properties

```
@IBOutlet var popupView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!
var blurEffect:UIVisualEffect!
```

in viewDidLoad put this code

```
    blurEffect = visualEffectView.effect
    visualEffectView.effect = nil
```

show a view/popup (a dialog) with blur

```
func presentPopUp() {
    self.view.addSubview(popupView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = self.blurEffect
       //make tarnsform from  popupView make it show more beauty
    }
}
```

hide a view/popup (a dialog) and blur

```
func dismissPopUp () {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.visualEffectView.effect = nil
        //make tarnsform from  popupView make it hide more beauty
    }) { (success:Bool) in
        //  dismissPopUp remove it from super View
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this also handle rotation ?

Comment: yes if there are constraints to handle it, literally   it's like a view