# Using Modal View Controllers and UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to solve the problem described in this blog post: http://justabeech.com/2014/10/22/using-uivisualeffectview-in-a-modal-view-controller/

I have a `UIViewController` with a storyboard modal segue to another `UIViewController` of which the `UIView` has a background colour of `[UIColor clearColor]`and a `UIVisualEffectView`.

When I present the view controller, the visual effect is blurred until the transition is completed and then the background turns grey again (exactly as displayed in the gif on that blog post).

[image]

I set the Modal Transition Style to FullScreen as specified, but still the same problem remains. What else could I be missing to make this work?

EDIT: Also, I get the following error:

`Warning: Attempt to present <ClocksDetailViewController: 0x7ff89cb5bc70> on <ClocksViewController: 0x7ff89c8afe90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Thanks

Comment: You need to take a snapshot of the "underneath" view and apply it as the background of the modal view.

Comment: I don't think this is it. The FullScreen presentation style should keep the views underneath.

Comment: You could easily find out by bugging the view after your modal transition. If the underneath VC should show through then it will still be in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Just done an experiment project with a VC with a red background and a full screen transition to a VC with a clear background... I was right.

Comment: Have you actually used the `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` mentioned in the article or have you used `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`? Note the difference.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. That's exactly it Sulthan, thanks!

Comment: Just see this post. copy and paste the code > https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400909/2283308

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have probably used `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` instead of the correct `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`.

With the old `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` all the views under the presented controller are removed from the view hierarchy once the animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the modal presentation style of the UINavigationController, instead of the the UIViewController.

```
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```